# spring 4.1.2' Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean is introducing an incompatibility from spring 4.0.x

Tags: spring

While Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean from Spring 4.0.5 was not making assumptions about ignoring unknown properties it is now explicitly disabling `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`. In my case it is breaking my code as I was always expecting an exception for unknown JSON elements in the payload.

Comment: And your question is..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is documented in their JavaDoc.